# value computed is not used

Tags: c, variables

How to fix this? Why the compiler claims of it if I am using the variable in another code parts?

```
void replace(char ** src, const char s, const char replace) {
   while(*(*src) != '\0') {
      if(* (*src) == s) {
         news[size] = replace;
      } else {
         news[size] = *(*src);
      }
      *(*src) ++; // the error line 
      size++;
   }
   *src = news;
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error you're getting?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: added full code.

Comment: @Jack: Yet not the error message... You're incrementing the value, not the pointer.  A `char**` dereferenced twice is a `char`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall He's getting "warning: value computed is not used" if he's using gcc.

Comment: I just got this from having a stray tilde (~) on a line by itself amongst a bunch of commented out (//) lines.  Not a syntax error like I'd expect in this case.  GCC 6.3.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `*(*src)++` you're basically dereferencing `src`, then doing a postfix increment on the pointer, *then* dereferencing the pointer. It's a bug. You're not using the final value, which is why the compiler warns you.

What you really want is `(**src)++`; i.e. dereference twice and then increment.

Comment: Postfix `++` and `*` do **not** have the same precedence, though prefix `++` and `*` do. The precedence they *do* have here doesn't change your reasoning, though.

Answer (score 0):

Double-dereferencing is very confusing; you should simplify the pointers:

```
char *srcp = *src;    // Or whatever type it is.
while (*srcp != '\0')
{
    if (*srcp == s)
    {
        news[size] = replace;
    }
    else
    {
        news[size] = *srcp;
    }
    srcp++;
    size++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The particular flags on your compiler does not allow you to derefrence a variable without using it.(assigning it to something) The problem is that you are derefrencing the pointer without using its value. The way to fix it is the following:

If you are trying to increment the pointer just do this:

> (*src) = (*src) + 1;

If you are trying to increment the final value, do this:

> ( **src) = ( **src) + 1;